# How to make values based on measures apprear on different rows instead of different columns

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I am creating a matrix in PowerBi and I created two measures to do so, but I see no option to have them appear on different rows as oppose to different columns, I am attaching a picture that shows the challenge clearly

I want orpinvoiced and orpbacklog on different rows not different columns

[image: I want orpinvoiced and orpbacklog on different rows not different columns]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to the **Values** settings under the **Format** tab and switch **Show on rows** to **On**.

[image: Screenshot]